# If a set of satisfiable theories all have the same models, must their intersection also have the same models?

Tags: model-theory

Let $T=\{{T_i:i\in I\}}$ be a set of theories indexed by and index set $I$. Assume that each theory is satisfiable, and that for any model $m$, $m$ models $T_i$ for some $i\in I$ iff $m$ models $T_j$ for any $j\in I$. Equivalently, all the theories in $T$ have the same models.

Let $S=\cap_{i\in I}T_i$ be the intersection of all the theories of in $T$. Must all models that model $S$ also model $T_i$ for any $i\in I$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Consider for example $T_1=\{\forall x\forall y(x=y)\}$ and $T_2=\{\forall x\forall y(y=x)\}$. Then the models of $T_1$/$T_2$ are exactly the one-element structures; but $T_1\cap T_2=\emptyset$ and *every* structure is a model of $\emptyset$.

We can fix this by looking at *deductively closed* theories, but then the answer is trivially yes: two deductively closed theories with the same classes of models are equal.

Comment: Thanks. I realize now my question was rather trivial. I'll have to rethink the issue I was trying to get at. In any case, thanks for your time.